# Postgres: How to combine "NOT IN" and JSON "->>"?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that says  "get all records where the foo_id inside the JSON of the 'data' column is not in a the bar table".  I've tried:

```
select * from json_table where (data->>'foo_id') not in (
    select bar.id from bar where bar.id is not null
);
```

However, I get an error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
```

Comment: BTW, probably, usage `NOT EXISTS` will be more efficient: `select * from json_table where not exists (select * from bar where bar.id is not null and (data->>'foo_id')::int = bar.id);` (also condition `bar.id is not null` is not necessary in this case)

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relation to your edit:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
```

Explicit typecasting!

```
select * from json_table where (data->>'foo_id')::integer not in (
    select bar.id from bar where bar.id is not null
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try ?..

```
select * from json_table where (data->>'foo_id') not in (
    select bar.id::text from bar where bar.id is not null
);
```

Comment: That was it.  I actually figured this out right after you submitted your answer, only I did it the other way (`(data->>'media_id')::integer`).  For future reference, either works (the point is to make their types line up).  Thanks!